# Freeform Next - Field validation options

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, solspace-freeform-next

Is there a way to control the validation options for fields in **Freeform Next** forms?

The default processing for email fields, for example, appears to simply be a check that somewhere within the string there is an @ symbol.

HTML5 field checking is more powerful - but  the documentation does not appear to discuss how to enable alternative validation methods.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Freeform Next 1.0.4 fixes the bug where email validation was not complete. :)
https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/changelog/